# Is Minecraft Windows 10 beta a separate purchase from the non-beta?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm thinking of buying Minecraft Windows 10 edition beta but when it leaves beta and its name changes to Minecraft Windows 10 edition, will I have to buy the game separately or will I get it if I had the beta already?

Answer (score 3):

**No, you won't have to.** For example, when Minecraft PC Edition was in Beta status, it costed less than now, however, those early buyers gained acces to download the Official Release Versions via the Launcher.
*So, buying it now might actually be better, getting it at a reduced price.*